# Access the fingerprint reader on client-side - ASP.NET MVC and WEBFORMS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I developed an ASP.NET MVC application, using a webforms page, in which it is called inside an MVC view. Because only from it, it's was possible to load the DLLs of the Biometric SDK, for active the biometric reader, for realize the capture and authentication the user's biometrics.

The Webforms page is called from the iFrame within certain views, which at certain times step a user ID parameter is sended for 1x1 comparison.

Okay, when I published for external access, and I connected the fingerprint reader to the computer that made access, the asp.net app does not detected the fingerprint reader on the client side, but it detected on the server side. And I needed it to be detected in the client-side. Any suggestions about how I can do this?

Thank you in advance, any collaboration.

Comment: that's the problem with server side code (like ASP.NET) - it has no access to client side hardware

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but isn't there any way to access the client side?

Comment: yes, with client side code - what is the client side for your application? a browser? does any browser have access to fingerprint reader?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, by the browser. i tested in chrome, firefox. However, just when i executing the web app in the server, the fingerprint reader is detected.

Comment: `i tested in chrome, firefox` - what exactly did you test? accessing a server that has server side code? I've already said the server can't access the client hardware, you need the client side to support the fingerprint reader, and there's no browser that I know of that supports accessing arbitrary hardware, nor any (standard) fingerprint API in any browser - I could be wrong, a quick search would determine if such a thing exists